# ListView double click pass value to a combobox in a different form

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've been trying to find a solution for my problem but i can't seem to. I have a form (Form_VerClientes) which is form that opens when I click a button on my other form (Form_Vendas).

This form (Form_VerClientes) is basically just for detecting which client the users want, trough their ID, and I want to whenever i double click a record in that listview the ID value of that same record to go to a combobox (cmb_cliente) that's held in the "Form_Vendas" form, and will represent the ID of the client.

Comment: How do you usually get data out of an object? You get a property or you call a method and get the return value. Why would this be any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second form declare an event and raise it when the user double clicks

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Event PropertyChanged As Action(Of Object)
    Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(ListView1.SelectedItems)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the first form handle the event

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents f2 As Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        f2 = New Form2()
        f2.Show()
        'or f2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
    Private Sub PropertyChanged(obj As Object) Handles f2.PropertyChanged
        'You have your object here
        MsgBox(obj.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Events are a nice way to send signals.

Comment: Just tried your code and it worked! This event stores the value of the variable you tell it to, and then you call that same event in the desired form to pass that value between forms, right?

Comment: Not exactly, when the event is raised, the argument is passed to the delegate { Action(Of Object) }. An Action is a function without return type with zero or more arguments (it is a generic delegate).
The event listener, first form, is called receiving the argument, and doing proper processing.
You can change Action(Of Object) to any type, in your case the ID is probably an Integer, so change to Action(Of Integer). In this case you have to alter also PropertyChanged(obj As Object) to PropertyChanged(obj As Integer) as the event delegate signature must match handler's.

Comment: By the way are you brazilian or portuguese?

Comment: I'm Portuguese, yes

Comment: So imagine i hadn't change Object to my data type, which would be Integer, would it assume automatically my data type, in my case ID being an Integer?

Comment: Yes, in vb.net this kind of boxing and unboxing are made at runtime, well, if you actually pass an Integer as argument, it will try at runtime to convert and if extists an imlplicit cast defined it will succeed.

[see this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/boxing-and-unboxing-in-VB-Net/)